# Getting window height on mobile (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile

How do I get window height on mobile? `$(window).height()` works fine on desktop, but as soon as I emulate a mobile device from Chrome dev tools, it reports back that the window height is `1739px`. Why is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/ebkeq/3/embedded/result/

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function() {

  // https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6306  
  alert($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: Are you adding viewport meta tag?

Comment: I tried so here but no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/ebkeq/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/aRHp7/1/show/ meta tag plus `$.mobile.getScreenHeight()`. Your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/ebkeq/6/show/ both fiddles return 460px

Comment: Nice! I thought `$.mobile.getScreenHeight()` was scheduled for removal though?

Comment: > both fiddles return 460px -- ah yeah. Thanks for the viewport tip!

Comment: I don't think it's going to be deprecated, It's a helper function. You're welcome :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/ebkeq/6/show/ works but not http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/ebkeq/6/embedded/result/ -- odd.

Comment: Result window is an iframe.

Comment: Maybe you should write a quick answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: go ahead and add it yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

See documentation on the window object here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Try

```
window.innerHeight
```

or

```
window.outerHeight
```

And for jQuery:

```
$(window).innerHeight()
```

http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

Comment: Sadly no. You can try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/ebkeq/7/embedded/result/